# Blue form background in IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

In http://www.milburndentonmoore.com/newsite/#contact, the sign-up form has a blue gradient background. Its supposed to be gray like the rest of the page. It's looking fine in Chrome and FF.

The form div is not linked, so I don't think there's any issue with borders.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: btw your document type is XHTML BUT the thing you created is not a valid XHTML! for example <img> <-- is not valid because it either must be <img></img> or <img />. aslo xhtml describes atributes that shouldn't be left out.

Comment: to follow up on what @ITroubs said, you may be better off switching your doctype to the HTML5 doctype rather than trying to fix your code to be valid xhtml. You should still make sure it validates though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form container has inline style

```
 <div class="ss-form-container" style="... filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#777, endColorstr=#777); ...">
```

This works in IE only and this is cause of gradient (tested with ie dev tools)

Answer (score 1):

In styles.css the background-color for the textareas are set to blue:

```
/* ========================== Form Elements Styles ========================== */
input, textarea {
    background-color: #424051;
```

Change the background color to the hex value you'd like, for grey you might like #333

Also to get rid of the dark outlines delete these:

```
box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #110f1c;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #110f1c;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #110f1c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your style.css on line 206

`input, textarea {background: rgba(111, 111, 111, 0.5);}`

Answer (score 0):

styles.css (line 206) seems to be the issue

```
input, textarea {
    background-color: #424051;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #110F1C inset;
    color: #F5F2EB;
}
```